# Pilot light not working at gas fireplace

Tags: gas, fireplace

my pilot igniter will not produce a spark.it is for a gas fireplace it is powered by four AA batteries at a wall switch, is there a way to test the igniter?

Comment: Stupid question: you already checked the batteries?

Comment: yes that's the first thing I did